# TableEditor in traitsui; 'selected' attribute keeps pointing to None, on_trait_change does not work

Tags: python, traits, traitsui

Dear community members,

I currently ran into a problem with the `TableEditor`'s `selected` attribute (traits version 4.5.0, traitsui version 4.5.1, Ubuntu). The problem occurs only for a special kind of Matryoshka structure, which is illustrated in the code below. Basically, no matter what, the `selected` keeps pointing at `None`. Correspondingly, watching for trait changes does not work.

Here is the code for illustration of my point:

```py
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Str, Float, Instance, Button
from traitsui.api import View, Item, TableEditor
from traitsui.table_column import ObjectColumn

table_editor = TableEditor(
    selected = 'selected_guy',
    columns = [ObjectColumn(name = 'name' , label = 'Name'),
               ObjectColumn(name = 'height', label = 'Height in meters')]

)

class TallGuy(HasTraits):
    name = Str('')
    height = Float(0) #in meters

class BunchOfTallGuys(HasTraits):
    selected_guy = Instance(TallGuy)
    bunch_of_guys = List(TallGuy,
                         editor = table_editor)
    whats_going_on = Button('What\'s going on?')

    def _whats_going_on_changed(self):
        print 'id of None: ', id(None)
        print 'id of selected_guy: ', id(self.selected_guy)

#this still works fine, the problem arises on the next level

class BunchWrapper(HasTraits):
    bunch = Instance(BunchOfTallGuys, required=True)

    traits_view = View(
            Item('object.bunch.bunch_of_guys', style='custom'),
            Item('object.bunch.whats_going_on')
        )

    def __init__(self):
        self.bunch = BunchOfTallGuys()
        self.bunch.bunch_of_guys.append(TallGuy(name='Larry', height = 1.8))
        self.bunch.bunch_of_guys.append(TallGuy(name='Garry', height = 2.0))
        self.bunch.bunch_of_guys.append(TallGuy(name='Jerry', height = 1.95))

bw = BunchWrapper()
bw.configure_traits()
```

If you now press the 'What's going on?' button, you will see that the id of `None` and of the `selected_guy` trait keeps the same regardless of what line in the `TabularEditor` you click. Is this expected behavior? Do you have any workaround for this, that allows to use the `Matryoshka` structure, that is otherwise beneficial for me to keep my code well-arranged?

Any suggestions will be welcome!

Regards,

Jan